# Animação Java Script

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando fazer um trabalho com css,html,js .Preciso fazer com que algumas imagens deslize para direita e esquerda assim que eu role a barra, uma imagem de cada vez, mas assim que eu rolo a barra as imagens se movimentação tudo ao mesmo tempo, pesquisei bastante e não consegui resolver esse problema.

```js
var t = 0;
var Velha , meninaGuarda;

function temporizar(){
 var r = window.pageYOffset;
 var a = window.innerHeight;
 var d = document.body.scrollHeight;
 t = r/(d-a);
}

function intervalo(inicio,fim,tempo){
 var i = (tempo - inicio) / (fim - inicio);
 if(i<0) i=0;
 if(i>1) i=1;
 return i;
}

function animar(){
 temporizar();

 var i = intervalo(0.2,0.6,t);
 meninaGuarda.style.left = ( (1-i)*0 + i*1400 ) + "px";
 Velha.style.left = ( (1-i)*1400 - i*0 )+ "px";
}


function iniciar(){
 Velha = document.querySelector("article#velha");
 meninaGuarda = document.querySelector("article#meninaguarda");
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",animar);

window.addEventListener("load",iniciar);
```

```css
html, body{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(hsl(200,60%,30%), hsl(200,100%,10%));
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#rolagem{
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
height: 1500%;
top: 0px;
}

article{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
}
   
#velha{
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-image:url('velha.png');
top: 500px;
height: 250px;
left:1400px;   
}
#meninaguarda{
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-image:url('meninaguarda.png');
top: 500px;   
height: 250px;
width: 140px;

}
   
#Fundo{
background-size: 550px 349px;
background-image: url('prédios.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x; 
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
position: fixed;
top:350px;   
}

#titulo{
 
 font-family: zapfino;
 font-size: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 top: -150px;
 left:500px;
}

#Principal{
 
 margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Cloe</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Cloeteste.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Cloeteste.css"/>
 
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div id="Principal">
 <h1 id="titulo">Clo&eacute</h1>
  <article id="Fundo"></article>
  <article id="velha"></article>
  <article id="meninaguarda"></article>
  
  <div id="rolagem"></div>
  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você parece estar querendo fazer um scroll horizontal, acredito que o caminho que seguiu chegou perto. Mas gostaria de ressaltar algumas coisas que podem ser o seu problema.
Matemática básica, qualquer número multiplicado por 0(zero) sempre vai ser zero, ou seja nos trechos a seguir o valor é sempre zero o que os torna irrelevantes na operação:

// ( (1-i)*0 + i*1400 ) + "px";
// ( (1-i)*1400 - i*0 )+ "px";

Outra coisa gostaria de sugerir que use o parseInt() que converte para numero inteiros, pelo que vi você deixa marge pra números quebrados, já explico, e isso, usando o parseInt, se o quiser claro, poderia ter algo assim:

```
meninaGuarda.style.left = parseInt( (1-i)*0 + i*1400 ) + "px";
Velha.style.left = parseInt( (1-i)*1400 - i*0 )+ "px";
```

Outra coisa que vi e que me deixou confuso com o cálculo que faz depois é sua verificação na função intervalo, onde você parece aceitar números entre 0 e 1, ou seja, 0.4 seria um número aceito.

Acredito que caso queira fazer um scroll horizontal como imagino, você devia pegar o scroll feito na página como já faz e somente add no left da imagem desejada. Caso queira movimentos mais rápidos ou mais lentos pra cada uma, sugiro uso de potência, ou add um número como 2 pra 1 imagem e 4 pra outra, que dai toda vez que for dar scroll vai sempre mover mais uma que outra.

Comment: Fiz alteração mas, continua com mesmo problema,as duas imagens se movimento no mesmo tempo.

Comment: Então mano, tu precisa adicionar tamanho diferentes para cada imagem que vai alterar, senão vai continuar a mesma coisa mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Jeferson, eu te aconselho a trocar a sua animação usando o style left por style transform translateX.
Com transform você pode saber, de forma assíncrona, quando a animação termina e também você vai tirar o processo de animação da main thread e fazer a gpu executar a animação.

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mouseover', Animation);

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mouseout', Animation);

document.querySelector('#div-top').addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('#div-bottom').classList.toggle('animation-right');
});

function Animation () {
 document.querySelector('#div-top').classList.toggle('animation-right');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Animation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <style>
           div {
               width: 24px;
               height: 24px;
               transform: translateX(0px);
               transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.785,.135,.15,.86);
           }
           #div-top {
               background-color: #673AB7;
           }
           #div-bottom {
               background-color: #03A9F4;
           }
           .animation-right {
               transform: translateX(48px);
           }
       </style>

       <div id="div-top"></div>
       <div id="div-bottom"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```